# git: Reverting changes of staged file

Tags: git, revert, staging

I had the following scenario:

I have my local branch and committed changes to the local branch.
Say my local branch is tracking the master branch from repository.

```
local ---> origin/master
```

Consider the file as a/b/c.d
I have modified contents of this my file in my local branch.

Now I wished to check out how things would behave with the original c.d with my other code changes.

So I did :

```
git checkout origin/master a/b/c.d
```

Now I wish to go back to the original file in my local branch commit.

I did:

```
git reset a/b/c.d
git checkout -- a/b/c.d
```

I got back my original file (present in my local branch).

Is it the right way of doing things or there is a better way to discard the changes
and get the file in my local branch after:

```
git checkout origin/master a/b/c.d
```

Could not find a scenario after googling.

Thanks

Comment: You may use `git checkout -f` to restore all the contents of your current branch, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @lxanezis

Thanks. This works. I tested it out.

Comment: As long as you have no other changes you're going to lose, just reset the branch. `git reset --hard HEAD` or you can just reset the specific files `git reset HEAD a/b/c.d`

Comment: After : git reset HEAD a/b/c.d
One has to do git checkout -- a/b/c.d

Comment: I was looking for a singe command to combine:
git reset a/b/c.d
git checkout -- a/b/c.d